# How to systematically export all tables from a DB2 database schema to csv

Tags: db2, db2-luw

Is there a way using a DB2 database to systematically export all tables from a schema to separate csv files ? What I mean is to export all the tables in a schema without specifying table names. Maybe somehow getting all table names in a schema, then applying the export on those

Comment: Define "systematically". Is the `export` command not systematic enough?

Comment: @mustaccio So what i mean is to export all the tables in a schema without specifying table names. Maybe somehow getting all table names in a schema, then applying the export on those ?\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily create a small script that does this for you, or even do a loop on the command line. Assuming you are on a unix/linux platform something like below should do.

```
#> db2 connect to mydb

#> for t in $(db2 -x "select rtrim(tabschema) || '.' || rtrim(tabname) from syscat.tables where tabschema = 'DB2INST1'"); do db2 "export to $t.csv of del modified by coldel, select * from $t"; done
```

You can replace DB2INST1 with whatever schema you are interested in. If you want tables from several schematas you can use in:

```
#> for t in $(db2 -x "select rtrim(tabschema) || '.' || rtrim(tabname) from syscat.tables where tabschema in ('DB2INST1', ...)"); do db2 "export to $t.csv of del modified by coldel, select * from $t"; done
```

There are a lot of options that you can use to format the output from export, here I use modified by coldel but there is much more that you can configure. See:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008303.html

for more info.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of scripting you can certainly do something like this:

```
db2 -x list tables for schema your_schema | \
awk '{print "export to "$1".csv of del select * from "$2"."$1}' | \
db2 +p -x
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that via the SQL inteface, e.g. a JDBC client, you might employ the [`ADMIN_CMD()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023573.html) system stored procedure and run this compound statement:

```
begin 
  for r as c1 cursor with hold for 
    select tabschema, tabname from syscat.tables 
    where tabschema = 'YOUR_SCHEMA' 
  do 
    call admin_cmd(
      'export to /some/path/'||rtrim(r.tabname)||
      '.csv of del select * from '||rtrim(r.tabschema)||'.'||rtrim(tabname)); 
  end for; 
end
```

Note that the files will be created on the database server.

(Cursor declaraion requires `with hold`, because `ADMIN_CMD()` commits at the end of every invocation.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://www.sql-workbench.eu/  SQL Workbench/J is a free, DBMS-independent, cross-platform SQL query tool.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try something like this:

```
db2move sample export -aw -l lobs -ts USERSPACE1
```

Comment: does db2move produce csv output? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002079.html